# Viewing Microblaze Processor Output with out Serial Port

Tags: fpga, xilinx, spartan, microblaze, xilinx-edk

I am experimenting with some Old Legacy Spartan 3 , 6 and Virtex 5 Series Kits as a part of research work. I am currently designing a microblaze processor systems. Is it possible that without using RS232 cable interface I can view the results on Console like a normal C/C++ application. ?

Comment: Results of what? Can you describe the problem a little bit more :)

Comment: printing statements like hello word on console. Like MS visual studio.

Comment: There are applications that use the Microblaze Debug Module for serial communication. But, you don't want an RS232 interface. If you have a development board with an OLED screen, then you may want to print your *results* there? Onboard LEDs would also be a good choice to represent the status of your application..